# Expected an indented block after "if"

Tags: godot, gdscript

what am i doing wrong this is my code and **my error is on the 2nd line** also im using **godot** and i'm using **gdscrpt** inside **godot** and **this is not all of my code its just the code that i got the error on**

```
if is_on_wall():
if spritedir == "left" and test_move(transform, Vector2(-1,0)):
    anim_switch("push")
if spritedir == "right" and test_move(transform, Vector2(1,0)):
    anim_switch("push")
if spritedir == "up" and test_move(transform, Vector2(0,-1)):
    anim_switch("push")
if spritedir == "down" and test_move(transform, Vector2(0,1)):
    anim_switch("push")
```

Answer (score 3):

as the error says you need to indent the code after the first if:

```
if is_on_wall():
    if spritedir == "left" and test_move(transform, Vector2(-1,0)):
        anim_switch("push")
    if spritedir == "right" and test_move(transform, Vector2(1,0)):
        anim_switch("push")
    if spritedir == "up" and test_move(transform, Vector2(0,-1)):
        anim_switch("push")
    if spritedir == "down" and test_move(transform, Vector2(0,1)):
        anim_switch("push")
```

Answer (score 2):

GDScript has a similar syntax to Python. When you declare a conditional statement like "if", you need to indent the code below your condition.

```
if x == y:
    # All the code with indent.
    pass
```

When you indent the code, you are actually saying that it belongs to the scope of your conditional statement. Therefore, if you do not indent after an "if" statement it will bring an error, because in case of True/False, there is nothing to be executed.